# Using a variable to represent a function in C

Tags: c, pointers, function

This has the functionality I want (and it works)

```
#include <stdio.h>
//includes other libraries needed

int foo();

int main() 
{
    while(true) 
    {

        while(foo()==1) 
        {
            //do something
        }

        //does other unrelated things

    }

}

int foo() 
{
    // Returns if a switch is on or off when the function was called 
    // on return 1;
    // off return 0;
}
```

However, I would like this to happen:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//includes other libraries needed

int foo();

int main() 
{
    while(true) 
    {
        //THIS IS THE PROBLEM
        int something = foo();

        while(something==1) 
        {
            //do something
        }

        //does other unrelated things

    }

}

int foo() 
{
    // Returns if a switch is on or off when the function was called 
    // on return 1;
    // off return 0;
}
```

How can I have the something variable update each time the inner while loop is called? I know it has something to do with `&` or `*` for references and pointers but I haven't been able to find an example online about this.

Also I cannot edit anything within the `foo()` function.

Comment: If such a thing were possible, what are you gaining from it?

Comment: int (*something)() = foo; while(something()==1) ... ?

Comment: There is some confusion in the answers regarding what you're asking. Would you like the variable to represent the *function itself*, or the *result of the function*?

Comment: The result of the function at the time the variable is accessed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is what you mean: it uses the function pointer to represent the function `foo`. Later it assigns it to a function `bar`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//includes other libraries needed

int foo();
int bar();

int main() 
{
    while(true) 
    {
        int (*something)() = &foo;

        while(something()==1) 
        {
                something = &bar;
        }

        //does other unrelated things

    }

}
```

Comment: Depending on the details, it may be worth considering a for loop - "for (something = &foo; something () == 1; something = &bar);"

Answer (score 6):

Since foo() is returning a value, you need to call the function again to get the latest
value.  The concise way to do that in C is to do the assignment and check together:

```
while ((something = foo()) == 1)
{
     // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To represent a function in a variable use a [function pointer](http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html)

```
 int (*something)() = &foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this for your loop:

```
while(true) 
{
    int something = foo();
    // do whatever here

    if (!something) continue;
    do 
    {
      //do something
    } while(foo()==1)

    //does other unrelated things
}
```

This is assuming, from your example, that you want to have the something variable to do stuff with before the loop, and don't want a new call to foo() before going into your loop.

If not, then as mentionned in another post you can just do `while(something = foo()) == 1)`